# Find the derivatives of the following function and calculate $f'(1)$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$f(x)=\prod_{n=1}^{100}(tan\frac {\pi x^n}{4}-n)$

I can solve the second question,use $g(x)=\prod_{n=2}^{100}(tan\frac {\pi x^n}{4}-n)$ and I can get $f(x)=(tan\frac {\pi x^n}{4}-n)g(x),n=1$.

But I want to know if there is any other way to solve it?

And how I can solve the first question?

thanks very much.

Comment: Don't use \prime. It does not do what is likely intended. Just use ' for derivatives. I don't know that I have ever actually seen \prime used except for derivatives and it doesn't really look right.

Comment: Ok,thanks your remind.

Comment: Sure thing :) It's a weird function that I think probably shouldn't exist in $\rm\LaTeX$ for exactly this reason.

Comment: @CameronWilliams: Maybe instead of $f\prime(x)$ "f\prime(x)" they expect people to write $f^\prime(x)$ "f^\prime(x)"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have
\begin{align}
f(x) = \prod^{100}_{n=1}\left(\tan\frac{\pi x^n}{4}-n \right)
\end{align}
then it follows
\begin{align}
f'(x)=&\ \sum^{100}_{j=1}\left\{ \left(\frac{j\pi x^{j-1}}{4}\sec^2\frac{\pi x^j}{4} \right)\prod^{100}_{n=1\\ n\neq j}\left(\tan\frac{\pi x^n}{4}-n \right)\right\}.
\end{align}
Setting $x=1$ yields
\begin{align}
f'(1) =&\ \sum^{100}_{j=1}\left\{ \left(\frac{j\pi }{4}\sec^2\frac{\pi}{4} \right)\prod^{100}_{n=1\\ n\neq j}\left(\tan\frac{\pi}{4}-n \right)\right\}=\sum^{100}_{j=1}\left\{ \frac{j\pi}{2}\prod^{100}_{n=1\\n\neq j}(1-n)\right\}\\
=&\ \frac{\pi}{2}\left\{ \prod^{100}_{n=2}(1-n)\right\} = -\frac{\pi}{2} 99!
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you very much,this answer is very nice.